# VS2012 not showing images uploaded by controller

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a page for uploading images,it works good,but when I want to show that uploaded image in a view I can't.

My images are stored in Images/products/{product name}/

In view I wrote

```
@Foreach(var item in product.images){
    <img src="~/images/products/{productname}/@item.name" />
}
```

//my name spell are correct

In debug src has correct value but doesn't show image,
But when I give an URL from content folder it shows  that image,
Even in solution explorer. VS doesn't show uploaded images and created folders by controller codes,

Comment: Are you sure that folder name is correct? If you browse the the path manually, does it display the image? 'http://localhost/images/products/{product name}/myimage.jpg'

Comment: When I type image URL in address bar browser gives 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to add permission to Images/products{productName} folder.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on the web site or application that serves the images
3. Click the "Basic Settings link on the right - take note of the App
   Pool name and cancel that dialog.
4. Click on Application Pools in the server tree on left In the list of
   app pools - note the identity for the app pool with the name you
   noted in step 3
5. Now in Windows Explorer, you can right click the image folders,
       choose properties, and click the click the security tab. Find the
       user associated with the identity used by the app pool. If it's not
       there then there's no permissions If it's there, click on it and
       look in the permissions pane to make sure "Read" is checked (or write/modify or even full control if you need).

you will need to repeat the step if you add sub folder manually on the Images folder

It's a best practice to save image on Content file since it by default already have read access. or another way is you could save your file on App_Data or hosting the file on cloud (with time limit to show for better security).

Comment: Thanks,I solved it by your guidance.but asome more changes was necessary